# Cannot find text by xpath (scrapy)

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I try to use xpath to get the date from the example listed below.

```
<node>
    <table>
        <td>
            <font style="font-size:14px">http://www.aaa.com</font>

             &nbsp;&nbsp;2016-10-11 17:14:11

        </td>
    </table>
</node>
```

I used code looks like:

```
response.xpath('/node/table/td/text()[2]').extract()
```

However it does not work. I expect it will return u'[  2016-10-11 17:14:11], but it return []. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

you can try following xpath

```
response.xpath('/node/table/td/font/following-sibling::text()[1]').extract()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried the method you provided. The description ('/node/table/td/font/following-sibling::text()[1]') works on developer tool of Chrome. However, it still not works in my scrapy program.

Comment: Have you checked the original HTML source code? Often, web browsers alter the document to fix broken or non-standard HTML. So what works in your browser's dev tools may not be the same as what scrapy (and lxml underneath) interprets.